# grails json marshalling

Tags: json, grails

I have a domain object which has a 1 - M relationship with another domain object e.g.

Person 1 -> M Langauges

I have registered a JSON object marshaller to marshall the Person object. A use case I am dealing with is displaying the Person in tabular format where the primary language is displayed by default.

The issue I have is when a user generates a search for language and I want to display the matching language for the person rather than the primary language.

The issue I have is that I do not know how to access the language being searched in the object marshaller and as such I can't determine the matching language to render in the JSON for the tabular format.

Here's the sample code I have for the Person:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Person) {  

 def returnArray = [:]
    returnArray['id'] = it.id
    returnArray['name'] = it.displayName?:""
    //I would like to be able to get the language matching a search param here
    //when a search has been carried out
    returnArray['language'] = it.primaryLanguage?:""

  }
```

At the moment, the workaround I have is to have a PersonWrapper where I pass the search term in the constructor, register an object marshaller for the wrapper and filter in the wrapper.

This seems pretty wasteful to me as I need to iterate over my domain results and create a wrapper for each instance.

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you're looking for something like that:

```
def filterLang = Language.findByCode("de")

// search for persons having the filter language assigned
def foundPersons = Persong.executeQuery("select p from Person as p inner join p.languages as lang where lang = :filterLang",[filterLang : filterLang])

def json = []

foundPersons .each {
    json << [id: it.id, name: it.name, language: filterLang]
}

render json as JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds very complicated for such a common use case. you can search through your persons and corresponding languages by using a criteria and than convert the result into a appropriate json format. e.g.

```
def result = Person.createCriteria().list {
   language {
      eq("lang", "de") // could be your search term
   }
} // you can also use hql to achieve our requirement

def json = []

result.each {
    json << [id: result.id, name: result.name, ...]
}

render json as JSON
```

Comment: thx for that. i have my query in that form, is the problem is that when I get the person back from hibernate all the languages are loaded, where as I really only want to filter the matching language to present to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

You can to filter your query and prepare it to render:

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification

List list = Person.withCriteria {
  maxResults 5
  resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
  alias 'languages', 'lan'
  projections {
    property 'id', 'id'
    property 'displayName', 'name'
    property 'lan.language', 'language'
  }
  eq 'lan.language', 'FR'    
}
```

then you can to use the result

```
render list as JSON
```

You must to use `resultTransformer` and set `alias` for each `property`. Thus you can create custom renders for specific situations.

Note: that code has not be tested, is simply a rough idea.